# Layer style fails to set for temporary layers derived from same layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a QGIS python processing script where, for each output layer, a layer style is applied before exporting to kml and styled geopackage layer. This works for all my output layers EXCEPT for 3 layers: These layers are all derived from the same process- In this case, only one of the layers has its layer style applied- The other 2 refuse to.

I've tried
a) using the layer file from the layer that does work (2008) on the layers that don't (1990, 2016): Doesn't work
b) changing layer output parameters from 'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT to memory layers i.e.'OUTPUT': "memory:layername_123". Doesn't work
c) Doing the layer styling and export for each layer all at once, before moving onto the next. That doesn't work.

Is this a bug in QGIS?

I have had other issues whereby the layer name was inherited from the processname and would therefore overwrite outputs (i.e. 3x derived layers from a clip, all would be named 'clip' so when exporting to geopackage, only 1 layer called 'clip' would be present)

```
#export styled layers
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': in_Lucas,
        'OVERLAY': outputs['Titles']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['ClipLucas'] = processing.run('native:clip', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    # Drop field(s)
    alg_params = {
        'COLUMN': ['AREA_HA','SHAPE_Length','SHAPE_Area'],
        'INPUT': outputs['ClipLucas']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': "memory:LUCAS_"
    }
    outputs['DropFieldsLucas'] = processing.run('native:deletecolumn', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.pushInfo('Lucas 1990')
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'AreaF_ha',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Float
        'FORMULA': '$area/10000',
        'INPUT': outputs['DropFieldsLucas']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': "memory:LUCAS_1990"
        
    }
    outputs['Lucas1990'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.pushInfo('Lucas 2008')
    
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'AreaF_ha',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Float
        'FORMULA': '$area/10000',
        'INPUT': outputs['DropFieldsLucas']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': "memory:LUCAS_2008"
        
    }
    outputs['Lucas2008'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    feedback.pushInfo('Lucas 2016')
    
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'AreaF_ha',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Float
        'FORMULA': '$area/10000',
        'INPUT': outputs['DropFieldsLucas']['OUTPUT'],
        'OUTPUT': "memory:LUCAS_2016"
       }
    outputs['Lucas2016'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['Lucas2016']['OUTPUT'],
        'STYLE': stylefolder +' \\LUM_LUCAS2016.qml',
        'OUTPUT':QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['Lucas2016Styled'] = processing.run('qgis:setstyleforvectorlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    
    alg_params = {
        'AltitudeAddend': 0,
        'AltitudeField': 'altitude',
        'AltitudeInterpretation': 1,  # Use QGIS geometry Z value if present
        'AltitudeMode': 0,  # clampToGround
        'AltitudeModeField': 'alt_mode',
        'DateBeginField': '',
        'DateEndField': '',
        'DateStampField': '',
        'DateTimeBeginField': 'time_begin',
        'DateTimeEndField': 'time_end',
        'DateTimeStampField': 'time_when',
        'DescriptionField': ['LUCNA_1990','LUCNA_2008','LUCNA_2012','LUCNA_2016'],
        'ExportStyle': True,
        'InputLayer': outputs['Lucas2016Styled']['INPUT'],
        'LineWidthFactor': 2,
        'NameField': '',
        'OutputKmz': outputfolder + '/'+ forestname + '_LUCAS2016.kmz',
        'PhotoField': '',
        'TimeBeginField': '',
        'TimeEndField': '',
        'TimeStampField': '',
        'UseGoogleIcon': None
    }
    outputs['ExportKmzlucas2016Styled'] = processing.run('kmltools:exportkmz', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': outputs['Lucas2008']['OUTPUT'],
        #'STYLE': stylefolder + '\\LUM_LUCAS2008.qml'
        'STYLE': stylefolder + '\\test.qml'
        #'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['Lucas2008Styled'] = processing.run('qgis:setstyleforvectorlayer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)


    alg_params = {
        'AltitudeAddend': 0,
        'AltitudeField': 'altitude',
        'AltitudeInterpretation': 1,  # Use QGIS geometry Z value if present
        'AltitudeMode': 0,  # clampToGround
        'AltitudeModeField': 'alt_mode',
        'DateBeginField': '',
        'DateEndField': '',
        'DateStampField': '',
        'DateTimeBeginField': 'time_begin',
        'DateTimeEndField': 'time_end',
        'DateTimeStampField': 'time_when',
        'DescriptionField': ['LUCNA_1990','LUCNA_2008','LUCNA_2012','LUCNA_2016'],
        'ExportStyle': True,
        'InputLayer': outputs['Lucas2008Styled']['INPUT'],
        'LineWidthFactor': 2,
        'NameField': '',
        'OutputKmz': outputfolder + '/'+ forestname + '_LUCAS2008.kmz',
        'PhotoField': '',
        'TimeBeginField': '',
        'TimeEndField': '',
        'TimeStampField': '',
        'UseGoogleIcon': None
    }
    outputs['ExportKmzlucas2008Styled'] = processing.run('kmltools:exportkmz', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

    alg_params = {
        'AltitudeAddend': 0,
        'AltitudeField': 'altitude',
        'AltitudeInterpretation': 1,  # Use QGIS geometry Z value if present
        'AltitudeMode': 0,  # clampToGround
        'AltitudeModeField': 'alt_mode',
        'DateBeginField': '',
        'DateEndField': '',
        'DateStampField': '',
        'DateTimeBeginField': 'time_begin',
        'DateTimeEndField': 'time_end',
        'DateTimeStampField': 'time_when',
        'DescriptionField': ['LUCNA_1990','LUCNA_2008','LUCNA_2012','LUCNA_2016'],
        'ExportStyle': True,
        'InputLayer': outputs['Lucas2008Styled']['INPUT'],
        'LineWidthFactor': 2,
        'NameField': '',
        'OutputKmz': outputfolder + '/'+ forestname + '_LUCAS2008.kmz',
        'PhotoField': '',
        'TimeBeginField': '',
        'TimeEndField': '',
        'TimeStampField': '',
        'UseGoogleIcon': None
    }
    outputs['ExportKmzlucas2008Styled'] = processing.run('kmltools:exportkmz', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in my code which caused the path to the style file to be invalid.

Comment: There is a good library for that [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path)